# Fill R datatable upon condition with it's own value

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

given this data table as an example:

```
    ID   Type   W     X        Y        Z       D   stderr Zscore  BABA  ABBA  nsnps
1: D14     OG   P1    P2       X1 OUTGROUP  0.0000 0.000000 -4.100     0     0      0
2: D14     OG   P1    P2       X2 OUTGROUP  0.0000 0.000000  7.200     0     0      0
3: D14     OG   P1    P2       X3 OUTGROUP  0.0000 0.000000 -2.000     0     0      0
4: D14    REP   P1    P2       X1 OUTGROUP -0.0281 0.005291 -5.317 46148 48819 869128
5: D14    REP   P1    P2       X2 OUTGROUP  0.0413 0.005276  7.837 43594 40132 751945
6: D14    REP   P1    P2       X3 OUTGROUP -0.0177 0.005773 -3.072 43764 45344 787440
7: D14    EXP   P1    P2       X1 OUTGROUP -0.0226 0.006499 -3.485 44643 46712 835427
8: D14    EXP   P1    P2       X2 OUTGROUP  0.0472 0.006721  7.030 44123 40142 758734
9: D14    EXP   P1    P2       X3 OUTGROUP -0.0173 0.006892 -2.509 45022 46606 809031
```

I am trying to add a column to all row that have a type different from "OG". In this new column I am trying to put the Zscore from the corresponding row with the "OG" type.
Here is the expected output:

```
    ID   Type   W     X        Y        Z       D   stderr Zscore  BABA  ABBA  nsnps.  Zexpect
1: D14     OG   P1    P2       X1 OUTGROUP  0.0000 0.000000 -4.100     0     0      0  NA
2: D14     OG   P1    P2       X2 OUTGROUP  0.0000 0.000000  7.200     0     0      0  NA
3: D14     OG   P1    P2       X3 OUTGROUP  0.0000 0.000000 -2.000     0     0      0  NA
4: D14    REP   P1    P2       X1 OUTGROUP -0.0281 0.005291 -5.317 46148 48819 869128  -4.100
5: D14    REP   P1    P2       X2 OUTGROUP  0.0413 0.005276  7.837 43594 40132 751945   7.200
6: D14    REP   P1    P2       X3 OUTGROUP -0.0177 0.005773 -3.072 43764 45344 787440  -2.000 
7: D14    EXP   P1    P2       X1 OUTGROUP -0.0226 0.006499 -3.485 44643 46712 835427   -4.100
8: D14    EXP   P1    P2       X2 OUTGROUP  0.0472 0.006721  7.030 44123 40142 758734   7.200
9: D14    EXP   P1    P2       X3 OUTGROUP -0.0173 0.006892 -2.509 45022 46606 809031  -2.000
```

If the row with "OG" contain their own ZScore it's not an issue. I tried to do so but without success:

```
DT[Type!="OG", Zexpect:=Zscore, .("ID","Type")]
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you care about `Zexpect` being NA for the "OG" group, this should work for this dataset:

```r
DT[, Zexpect:= first(Zscore), by = .(ID, Y)]
```

To be more robust, you would likely want to join back on itself:

```r
DT[DT[Type == "OG"], on = .(ID, Y), Zexpect := i.Zscore]
```

In either case, it would be simple to assign `Zexpect` back to NA if it matters:

```r
## cleanup
DT[Type == "OG", Zexpect := NA_real_]

DT

##     ID Type  W  X  Y        Z       D   stderr Zscore  BABA  ABBA  nsnps Zexpect
## 1: D14   OG P1 P2 X1 OUTGROUP  0.0000 0.000000 -4.100     0     0      0      NA
## 2: D14   OG P1 P2 X2 OUTGROUP  0.0000 0.000000  7.200     0     0      0      NA
## 3: D14   OG P1 P2 X3 OUTGROUP  0.0000 0.000000 -2.000     0     0      0      NA
## 4: D14  REP P1 P2 X1 OUTGROUP -0.0281 0.005291 -5.317 46148 48819 869128    -4.1
## 5: D14  REP P1 P2 X2 OUTGROUP  0.0413 0.005276  7.837 43594 40132 751945     7.2
## 6: D14  REP P1 P2 X3 OUTGROUP -0.0177 0.005773 -3.072 43764 45344 787440    -2.0
## 7: D14  EXP P1 P2 X1 OUTGROUP -0.0226 0.006499 -3.485 44643 46712 835427    -4.1
## 8: D14  EXP P1 P2 X2 OUTGROUP  0.0472 0.006721  7.030 44123 40142 758734     7.2
## 9: D14  EXP P1 P2 X3 OUTGROUP -0.0173 0.006892 -2.509 45022 46606 809031    -2.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I might have been not specific enough in my example cause the non-robust does copy the 1st "OG" to all of them. The second option works perfectly fine ! Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

For each value of `W`, `X` and `Y` you can get corresponding `Zscore` for `Type = 'OG'`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)
DT[, Zexpect:= Zscore[Type == 'OG'], .(W, X, Y)]
DT[Type == 'OG', Zexpect := NA_real_]
DT

#    ID Type  W  X  Y        Z       D   stderr Zscore  BABA  ABBA  nsnps Zexpect
#1: D14   OG P1 P2 X1 OUTGROUP  0.0000 0.000000 -4.100     0     0      0      NA
#2: D14   OG P1 P2 X2 OUTGROUP  0.0000 0.000000  7.200     0     0      0      NA
#3: D14   OG P1 P2 X3 OUTGROUP  0.0000 0.000000 -2.000     0     0      0      NA
#4: D14  REP P1 P2 X1 OUTGROUP -0.0281 0.005291 -5.317 46148 48819 869128    -4.1
#5: D14  REP P1 P2 X2 OUTGROUP  0.0413 0.005276  7.837 43594 40132 751945     7.2
#6: D14  REP P1 P2 X3 OUTGROUP -0.0177 0.005773 -3.072 43764 45344 787440    -2.0
#7: D14  EXP P1 P2 X1 OUTGROUP -0.0226 0.006499 -3.485 44643 46712 835427    -4.1
#8: D14  EXP P1 P2 X2 OUTGROUP  0.0472 0.006721  7.030 44123 40142 758734     7.2
#9: D14  EXP P1 P2 X3 OUTGROUP -0.0173 0.006892 -2.509 45022 46606 809031    -2.0
```